# Is there a way to have a new PXDBDecimal field show null

Tags: acumatica

I have added PXDBDecimal user fields to an existing screen in the form section.  When creating a new record, these immediately show as '0.00' - I'd like to know if there's a way for it to just show empty / null.  I have no PXDefault attribute, so it's not set to default to 0.00.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the answer here: (Presumably this is the same case with PXDBInt and PXDBDecimal)

[Default [PXDBInt] data field to Null value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35343780/default-pxdbint-data-field-to-null-value/40135924#40135924)

Comment: I saw that, but I was hoping to keep the Decimal type as it's already been added to the db as Decimal.  I'm guessing that having a PXDBDecimal  type show as null on a new record isn't really possible..

Comment: You can still use the PXDBDecimal type. The "fix" is to change the Control on the screen to be PXTextEdit (instead of PXNumberEdit) and change the TextMode property of the control to "Number". The only thing I'm uncertain of is if the "Number" TextMode allows for a decimal character to be typed but I believe it does as long as it's bound to a Decimal type field.